# Process runtime not executing command onn Mac os youtube-dl command

Tags: java, linux, macos, youtube-dl

I am trying to execute command from java to MacOs terminal but is not working I search all over the internet and I can't find a solution when I try with mkdiris working with ls command no I use same code for linux and is working there the strange thing is that is working for wget command but for youtube-dl is appear a problematic. I also try with the full path of youtube-dl again it fails.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("links_sorted.txt");

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String [] command = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "youtube-dl " +  "'" + line + "'"};
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            System.out.println(line + " done downloading");
        }
        fr.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to handle stdin and stderr. Using `ProcessBuilder` should help

Comment: Hi can yout give an example code

Comment: You could do a lot worse than copying the [javadoc example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (You can leave out the env and assert stuff)